# An event for a certain key press regardless of focussed control [vb]

Tags: vb.net, events, keyboard-events

I have read around stackoverflow and found out how to create an event for when a certain key is pressed when a certain control is selected, but I would like to know how to register a key being pressed when any control is selected (edit: on the only window/form)?

Comment: It depends on the scope of where you want to trap the keypress from.  Just that Form?...just when your App (multiple Forms) is focused?  When any App is focused?...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean only when your form has focus then you can set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `True` and then the form will raise keyboard-related events first, regardless of what child control has focus.  If you mean even when your application is not active then you should look into the `RegisterHotKey` API.